# Boot issue's with 14.04 LTS and kernel 4.2.6 & 4.3 and also 15.10

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, 15.10

I bought a new Notebook HP Pavilion 15-ab118nc with Windows 10 on it, and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as dual boot. Originally it came with kernel 3.19.0-25-generic.

After some updates, kernel 3.19.0-33-generic was installed. Wifi options were not available, so after surfing around, I found more people have this issue when they have this wifi module:

> Intel dual band wireless-ac 3165

Solution is to go to kernel 4.2.X (I installed 4.2.6) and install these drivers:

```
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
```

After booting it get these messages:

```
[   0.048905] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[   2.851814] tmp_crb MSFT0101:00: A TMP error (2314) occurred continue selftest
```

**After this the boot hangs.** If I manually shutdown and reboot again, and when the first error message pops up, and I press rapidly a combination of <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will go through the messages to the login screen.

The wifi module is recognized and I can use wifi without issue's.

Then I upgraded to kernel 4.3, and also installed these drivers:

```
iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
```

After boot I still get these messages, although the number in front of it changes very time:

```
[   0.048905] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[   2.851814] tmp_crb MSFT0101:00: A TMP error (2314) occurred continue selftest
```

**Same story, after reboot it hangs**, but with pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> during boot, it goes through most of the times. And wifi works after that.

When I boot in the 3.19 kernel, no error messages, but also no wifi module is detected.

Google knows the first error message, and most replies to that one is that it is not important and you can ignore it. The second error message is completely unknown by google...

Can anyone help me to fix those error messages?

**==============  EDIT  ===============**

I tried now to install Ubuntu 15.10 from USB, and after choosing in the first menu "install ubuntu now", i get the same error message:

[   0.055892] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with these messages? Do you experience any concrete issues with your Ubuntu system?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, the laptop hangs, does not continue starting up. I need to do a hard reset after that, and choose windows or kernel 3.19 to be able to use the laptop.

Comment: Thanks for repeating that. I overlooked that in your questions and **other close-voters seem to have done the same**.

Comment: Ok, i have edited the text now and marked the hanging issue in bold now.
Anyone out there who can help ?

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, I finally made it work, so this can be closed.

Recap:

**Kernel 3.19**

Wifi firmware iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode

- Boots perfectly, but no wifi card detected

**Kernel 4.2.0**

Wifi firmware iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode

- 90% of the boots it hangs, but wifi works

**Kernel 4.2.6**

Wifi firmware iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode

And also

Wifi firmware iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode

- 95% of the boots it hangs, but wifi works

**Kernel 4.3**

Wifi firmware iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode

And also

Wifi firmware iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode

- 95% of the boots it hangs, but wifi works

**Solution**

I removed all 4.* kernels, deleted all wifi firmware files for those 4.* kernels, and booted back into kernel 3.19 and keeping the original firmware installed: iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode

Many hours of google later I found the suggestion to rename the firmware, which I tried as well:

cd /lib/firmware

sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode  iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode

sudo cp iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode  iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode

After reboot, it works !

Who knew, a simple thing like renaming the firmware file...

Case can be closed.


**PS, it does not solve the fact that kernel 4.2.x and 4.3 are not compatible with a Notebook HP Pavilion 15-ab118nc**